relative pronouns and their order in instruction manuals
I struggle with how pronouns are used in English sentences. I want to give an example of a sentence I have trouble comprehending.  This sentence below comes from documentation read by software engineers:

The lifecycle of the kubeadm CLI tool is decoupled from the kubelet,
which is a daemon that runs on each node within the Kubernetes
cluster.

Question 1: I do not understand what the word which is referring too.  Is the word which referring to the kubeadm CLI tool or is the word which referring to the kubelet?
Question 2: What procedure did you use to help you answer Question 1?
Question 3: Is the procedure you defined in Question 2 a strict rule followed by native English speakers?
Question 4: What level of English proficiency is normally required before someone is familiar with the procedure that you defined in Question 2?
Question 5: Would it have been more beneficial to rewrite the original sentence as two sentences and without the use of the word which.  For example:

The lifecycle of the kubeadm CLI tool is decoupled from the kubelet.
The kubeadm CLI tool is a daemon that runs on each node within the Kubernetes
cluster.

Note: replace the phrase in bold with that actual answer you provided in question 2
I think my two sentences convey the same meaning as the original message without any ambiguity. However, my approach comes at the cost of 6 additional ASCII characters.  Avoiding the use of pronouns can improve comprehension among non-native English readers/speakers.  Are there substantial drawbacks to my two sentence approach?

You have correctly identified the word which refers to. Many languages use "that/which/who" to refer right back to the last noun.

It seems to me the kubelet is the daemon. “ Since the kubelet is a daemon, it needs to be maintained by some kind of an init system or service manager. ”
